# Create API key in AWS API Gateway from AWS Lambda using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am using an AWS Lambda function to create an API key using Boto3.

Testing locally with the following is successful:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('apigateway')

response = client.create_api_key(
    name='test_user_from_boto',
    description='This is the description',
    enabled=True,
    generateDistinctId=True,
    value='',
    stageKeys=[{
        'restApiId':'aaa',
        'stageName':'beta'
    }]
)
```

This works no problem returning a dictionary as [expected](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_api_key). The return dictionary includes a `value` key that has the generated api key value which is what I'm after.

When doing something similar in AWS Lambda, the return dictionary does not include the `value` key.

This is my Lambda hander function.

```
import boto3


api_id = 'zzz'
plan_id_map = {
    'trial': 'aaa', 
    'basic': 'bbb', 
    'professional': 'ccc'
}

def handler(event, context):
    user_name = event['user_name']
    stage = event['stage']
    plan = event['plan']

    client = boto3.client('apigateway')
    api_key_response = client.create_api_key(
        name=user_name, 
        description='', 
        enabled=True, 
        # generateDistinctId=True, # including this argument throws an error
        # value='', # including this argument throws an error
        stageKeys=[{
            'restApiId': api_id, 
            'stageName': stage
        }]
    )

    user_key_id = api_key_response['id']
    user_api_key = api_key_response['value'] # throws a key error here

    plan_response = client.create_usage_plan_key(
        usagePlanId=plan_id_map[plan],
        keyId=user_key_id,
        keyType='API_KEY')    

    return {
        'user_name': user_name,
        'user_key_id': user_key_id,
        'user_api_key': user_api_key
    }
```

The results from printing `api_key_response` is the following:

```
{
    u'name': u'test_user_from_lambda', 
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'HTTPStatusCode': 201, 
        'RequestId': 'b8298d38-7aec-11e6-8322-5bc341fc4b73', 
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': 'b8298d38-7aec-11e6-8322-5bc341fc4b73',
            'date': 'Thu, 15 Sep 2016 02:33:00 GMT', 
            'content-length': '203', 
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    },
    u'createdDate': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 2, 33, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 
    u'lastUpdatedDate': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 2, 33, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 
    u'enabled': True, 
    u'id': u'xyzxyz', 
    u'stageKeys': [u'abcabc/beta']
}
```

When attempting to use `get_api_key`, I get a parameter validation error:

```
get_api_key_response = client.get_api_key(
    apiKey='585yw0f1tk',
    includeValue=True
)

Unknown parameter in input: "includeValue", must be one of: apiKey: ParamValidationError
```

Is the AWS`boto3` module modified to exclude the `value` key? How to return the generated api key?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: It's not an error, the key `value` just does get returned in the dictionary in the AWS Lambda implementation where it does otherwise.

Comment: So what does `api_key_response` look like at that point? Try printing it

Comment: Updated OP with the results

Answer (score 3):

The difference here can be attributed to different versions of the AWS SDK in your Lambda environment vs your development environment.

In newer versions of the SDK, the API key value is omitted from certain responses as a security measure. You can retrieve the API Key value via a separate call to [get_api_key](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_api_key) with includeValue=True

Comment: I've tried using `get_api_key` with the `includeValue=True` argument and `includeValue` fails parameter validation. See OP.

Comment: I should note that I'm using boto3 v1.3.1 on my dev environment which is the same as the AWS implementation.

Comment: I would suggest to bundle the latest version of the SDK (1.4) in your Lambda function. Lambda tends to lag behind on SDK releases. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html